# How can I chain a tty over multiple ssh hops

Tags: ssh, tty

I have a target-server that is accessible by middle-server, and I want a terminal from my localhost to target-server, through middle-server.

No need to open a port in my localhost.

Comment: [openssh jump host](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two)

Comment: Sorry, I searched before I asked, but I didn't know that "jump host" was the right term to search for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a command to execute in a remote host just after establishing the ssh connection. Therefore, you can open a connection to your middle host, and then chain an additional ssh connection to your target server. Keep in mind that the chained command will execute **at the remote host**. This is particularly important if some of the IP addresses are set by local networks, behind NATs, etc. You could build a longer chain if you needed more hops.

```
ssh -A -t -p middle-port middle-user@middle-server ssh -A -p target-port target-user@target-server
```

If you need to use a certificate in some of the hops (lets say, to reach the middle server), then you should insert the -i argument in the first level of the chain. You might be prompted for a passphrase, if that is the case:

```
ssh -i ~/mykey.pem -A -t -p middle-port middle-user@middle-server ssh -A -p target-port target-user@target-server
```